# Swift: Dictionary of strings with a unique keys and a groups of values that match the keys

Tags: arrays, string, swift, dictionary

How we can **create sorted Dictionary** in Swift like in example?

Values data in arrays is random. Array of values may be longer.

```
var exampleData = [ [["Section1" : ["11","Green"]   ],
                     [["Section1" : ["23","Blue"]    ],
                     [["Section1" : ["344","Yellow"]  ],
                     [["Section2" : ["100","Tall"]    ],
                     [["Section2" : ["232","Short"]   ],
                     [["Section3" : ["112","Number"]  ],
                     [["Section3" : ["222","String"]  ],
```

```
var sortedData = [["Section1" : [ ["11","Green"],  ["23","Blue"],["344","Yellow"] ]],
                  ["Section2" : [ ["100","Tall"],  ["232","Short"] ]],
                  ["Section3" : [ ["112","Number"],["222","String"] ]]]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us your implementation so we can understand it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  But you can pull all the values into an array of tuples and sort those.  Or alternatively just start with an array of tuples and only add values if:

1. If the key value is unique (the first value in the tuple at each array index), or
2. If the key value preexists, then update the tuple of values with the new tuple to be entered.

Be sure to resort after every new item addition.